# What can be space efficient algorithm for Single row of skyscraper puzzle

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem which is a single row variant of [skyscraper puzzle](http://www.brainbashers.com/skyscrapers.asp). The problem statement is:

Consider a single row of a skyscraper puzzle of size nxn. If we know how many buildings can be seen from the left, and from the right, of the row, how many different ways are there of populating that row with buildings of heights 1..n? (1<=n<=5000)

I am solving it with bottom up dynamic programming. Recurrence relation is following:

```
f(n,left,right)=(n-2)*f(n-1,left,right) + f(n-1,left-1,right) +f(n-1,left,right-1)
f[1][1][1]=1;
```

Don't worry about big numbers in answer as I am supposed to show modulo result. I am able to get correct answer from this but the memory requirement for this algorithm is very high. Space Complexity for this will be O(n^3) which is too much for given problem since n can be upto 5,000.

Can you please suggest me some alternate algorithm?

Edit:

For explanation of my recurrence relation:
consider all combination with (n-1) height and now add 1 height to all the building. This will give us buildings from 2,3 to n. Now only building with height 1 has to be adjusted. It can be adjusted on either sides which is second and third term int addition. 
If it is inserted in not on the sides, then that is represented by first term in addition. Please let me know if it is still unclear, I would really appreciate any help

Comment: I find this quite interesting; surely you mean 'with height _at most_ `n`'? Please explain the recurrence relation in a bit more detail. I somehow believe the maximum height needed can be bounded somehow...

Comment: Not only at most n, it is given that buildings are of height 1,2,3 till n, only different permutations are required. For for explaining my recurrence: consider all combination with (n-1) height and now add 1 height to all the building. This will give us buildings from 2,3 to n.  Now only building with height 1 has to be adjusted. It can be adjusted on either sides which is second and third term addition or in between the two sides which is first term in addition. Please let me know if it is still unclear, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Codor I have been stuck on this problem for very long. I would really be grateful for your help.

Comment: @Codor Ohh, anyways thanks a lot for your time. I hope you were able to understand my approach? I fear that this question might go unanswered. Any suggestion of active forums where I can find online help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57672/discussion-between-naman-and-codor).

Comment: @Codor I don't know about that but I am more concerned about space complexity. I can't have an array of 5000*5000*5000. It requires too much of memory.

Comment: @Naman I suggest you to put a bounty for this if you want to get more attention :)

Comment: @PhamTrung Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Actually it required some reputation and that time I was really short of it. :)  Your solution seems correct to me. I am going through it. I will accept it once I completely grasp it.

Comment: No problem, just read it and see if my answer can help you :) any question you can ask me. I believe your problem was also asked in one previous Topcoder round (problem B div 1 I believe) so If you can spend time and dig through it, you can find something interesting :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I truly appreciate your help. I am digging through it. I saw this problem in ICPC USA southeast 2013. I really wanna be able to solve DP on my own. Would try to solve at least 4-5 DP problem a week from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to solve this problem we need to make several observations:

- First, the highest building will separate the view from left and right, so, if we can decide the position of the highest building, we can solve the left and right view problem separatedly.
- Assuming that we have a function `f(x, n)` which calculate the number of ways we can see `x` buildings out of `n` building from one side. So, after we decide the position of the highest building, the result will be `f(left - 1, a - 1)*f(right - 1, n - a - 1)*c(a - 1, n - 1)` with `a` is the position of the highest building, `a - 1` will be the number of buildings at the left side of the highest building, and function `c(a - 1,n - 1)` calculates number of way to pick `a - 1` buildings out of `n - 1` buildings (Because we need to pick randomly `a - 1` buildings to put to the left side).

So, we can create a `dp[n][n]` table to store result of function `f(x, n)`. And for each position `a` of the highest building:

we have `answer += dp[left - 1][a - 1]*d[right - 1][n - a - 1]*c[a - 1][n - 1]`.

To calculate table `dp[n][n]` in O(n^2) time complexity, we need to make some other observations:

- For each `dp[x][y]`, we have `dp[x][y] = sum of dp[x - 1][y - z - 1]*P(z, y - 1)` , which means we select `z` buildings and hide them randomly after the highest building (the highest building is always counted in those seen buildings). Function `P` is to calculate the permutation.
- As `P(a,b) = b! / (b - a)!`, so, we can see that if we use an extra array `total` , which store `total[x] += dp[x][y]/ y!`, we have:

  ```
   dp[x][y] = total[x - 1]* (y - 1)!
            = (dp[x - 1][0]/0! + dp[x -1][1]/1! + ... + dp[x - 1][y - 1]/ (y -1)!)*(y - 1)!
            = dp[x - 1][0]*P(y - 1, y - 1) + dp[x - 1][1]*P(y - 2, y - 1) + ...
  ```

  thus, we can calculate `dp` in O(n^2):

  ```
   for(int y = 1; y <= n; y++){
       for(int x = 1; x <= y; x++){
           dp[x][y] = total[x - 1]*(y - 1)!;
           total[x] += dp[x][y]/y!;
       }
   }
  ```

And with this, we complete our problem, keeping both time and space complexity in **O(n^2)**.

**Note**: after going through the [problem statement](https://ser.cs.fit.edu/ser2013/problems/), we need to calculate the number of way mod 1000,000,007, so you should use modulus inverse for this problem, which also help to avoid precision problem.

Comment: I went through the solution. Although I have a small doubt, why do we need a two dimensional DP, the first dimension 'a' is never changing? I mean, we always just need dp[left-1][b] and dp[right-1][b] for all b's. But the first dimension is fixed. Am I doing some mistake?

Comment: Really elegant solution. Took me a bit time to understand it. Although I feel there is a small typo. In the equations, for dp[x][y], last and second last line says, dp[x][y]=(dp[x-1][0]*P(0,y-1) + ...... ),   I guess it should be dp[x][y] = ( dp[x-1][0]*P(y-1,y-1) + .... ). Am I making some mistake? Although this doesn't change the total solution.

Comment: @Naman does my answer make sense? if yes can you vote this up :)

Comment: Yes it surely does. Sorry that I didn't do it earlier. I have upvoted as well accepted it as it solves the primary premise of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain a potential solution in pseudocode, hopefully I don't mix up some indices; if the solution works, the space complexity can be reduced to `O(n*n)`. Supposing that the recurrence relation given above

```
f[1][1][1]=1;
f(n,left,right)
  =(n-2)*f(n-1,left,right)+f(n-1,left-1,right)+f(n-1,left,right-1)
```

is evaluated as

```
let f:int[N][N][N];
f(1,1,1) = 1;
for ( int n = 0; i < N; n++ )
  for ( int left = 0; left < N; left++ )
    for ( int right = 0; right < N; right++ )
      f(n,left,right)
        = (n-2)*f(n-1,left,right)+f(n-1,left-1,right) +f(n-1,left,right-1);
```

the evaluation can be changed by using only two "slices" for the outermost dimension as follows.

```
let slice1:int[N][N];
let slice2:int[N][N];
slice1(1,1) = 1;
for ( int n = 0; i < N; n++ )
  for ( int left = 0; left < N; left++ )
    for ( int right = 0; right < N; right++ )
      slice2(left,right)
        = (n-2)*slice1(left,right)+slice1(left-1,right)+slice2(left,right-1);
      exchange slice1 and slice2
```

Hopefully the idea becomes clear in this notation. The basic idea is to note that for generation of the `n`-th slice, only the `n-1`-th slice is necessary. The idea is similar to the fact that [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) can also be evaluated in linear space, as for the generation of the 'n'-th row only the `n-1`-th row is necessary; in total, for both problems, a naive evaluation can be improved in terms of space complexity by not storing all intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This will surely bring down the space requirements to O(n^2). If you have idea about better time complexity than O(n^3), I would really welcome that. But for this question my primary problem is solved. I somehow feel that using just permutation and combination even time complexity can be brought down.

Comment: Thanks a lot too, it was fun and I was lucky in finding an idea. Is your question answered somehow?

Comment: I would say that my primary question is definitely answered. But I was hoping if someone could suggest completely alternate approach than DP may be with just permutation and combination. This problem was asked in ICPC USA southeast 2013. Thanks again for letting me know this trick. I think this can be used to any DP where we are dependent only on previous stage.

Comment: Yeah true. I hope I can get a faster algorithm also because O(n^3) with n=5000 will get good enough time.

Comment: You can look at my answer for an O(n^2) time and space solution :)